# How to set a non-email apple-id for iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore, apple-id

I have 2 apple-ids, "logistes" which I started using years ago, and which I have used to make all my app-store purchases, and another me.com email based one that I use for iCloud data - contacts, Safari settings etc.

I recently had to reset my iPad when updating to a beta version of iOS left me unable to get internet. As I got back into the machine entered the me.com email and the password and that worked fine. But when I went to sign in as my older apple-id there doesn't seem to be a way.

From the Updates tab of AppStore I signed in with the me.com, then the dialog showed the option to edit my Apple ID. Clicking that takes me to Safari, pointing at appleid.apple.com, where I then try to sign in as "logistes".

Then it tells me that an email address is required, and shows me the email address I used with logistes. Then it tells me "This email address is not available for use as an Apple ID. You may already have an Apple ID associated with this address. Please try again or sign in using your existing Apple ID"

And that is as far as I have managed to get.

Does anyone know what I need to do at this point?

Comment: Are you sure it isn’t the same Apple id?

Comment: Yes, different associated email address, different password.